# Experimental evidence for $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, momentum, mass, acceleration

Newton's 2nd Law says $\vec{F}= \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$ .

In a constant mass system this becomes $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$. Answers to why $F=ma$ can be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172848/why-does-f-ma-is-there-a-straightforward-reason).

However, in a variable mass sytem [(see derivation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-mass_system#Derivation) Newton's 2nd law still applies and it becomes ${\mathbf  {F}}_{{{\mathrm  {ext}}}}+{\mathbf  {v}}_{{{\mathrm  {rel}}}}{\frac  {{\mathrm  {d}}m}{{\mathrm  {d}}t}}=m{{\mathrm  {d}}{\mathbf  v} \over {\mathrm  {d}}t}$
. What experimental evidence is there for this (both that Newton's law will apply and/or that this equation is correct)?

Comment: This question needs more focus: this is more of a "list question" that is just asking for examples. Is there something conceptual about variable mass systems that you do not understand? That would be a better question for this site.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Yes, this is true. I think a new Meta post might be useful. I agree list questions can be very good questions that cover good physics and attract excellent answers; however, we should also consider the context of a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @BioPhysicist [Done](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13518/when-are-questions-with-multiple-different-possible-answers-good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Rocket Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) makes use of this variable mass relationship since rockets change weight as they use propellant. So every rocket is experimental evidence of this relationship.

Comment: Yes, that's true. We could say that since the variable mass equation is true the formula it was derived from ($F=\frac{dp}{dt}$) is also true. However, this would be affirming the consequent.

Comment: You can't measure $p$ any more directly than by measuring mass and velocity. If you're wondering is there any experiment where we measure $p$ directly the answer is no. It's calculated from other quantities.

Comment: I never said you could measure $p$ directly. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-mass_system#Derivation.

Comment: I believe that for experimental evidence, it is necessary to measure $F$ by another device, as a load cell which indicates the inertial force acting on some mass in the rocket against its wall for example.

Comment: @user716881 If you agree you can't measure $\vec{p}$ directly, then how could you experimentally show that $\vec{F} = \frac{d}{dt}\vec{p}$?

Answer (score 1):

Classical physics is not just a set of independent ideas, it is a set of connected ideas, and consequently almost any process involving mass moving from one system to another will offer evidence of the correctness of the 2nd law as it applies to such systems. Simple examples include collisions, rockets, and moving platforms (e.g. a cart, a boat, a car, a train) where some mass falls on the platform or is thrown out. You could also consider a comet, a meteor, a leaky bucket, etc. One never gets complete proof in the sense of a logical deduction, but one gets evidence that the set of ideas is correctly describing the phenomena, and one builds on those ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of this is where the mass changes under a scenario of no external force.
There is a classic problem of rain falling into the bed of truck, where one ignores the friction between the truck and the road.

If you have an airtrack, you could do the experiment where you a car slowly slides under its own inertia (F = 0) with a cup attached to the top of the car.  You then incrementally add water from a pipet.  If you define the system to be the moving car and cup, which doesn't experience an external forward force (but not the falling water), then when the water enters the car, the mass increases but at the expense of the velocity.

Alternatively, you can define your system to be the car and falling water.  None of these experience a sideways force.  Here the mass remains constant, though initially the masses are moving at different horizontal velocities.  Horizontal velocity of the car > 0, Horizontal velocity of the falling water = 0.